# Displaying a Twitter Profile Picture from XML file

Tags: php, xml, twitter

Currently I'm displaying tweets from a geocode along with the tweet itself along with the user name and the time and date it was tweeted. But now Im trying to access the profile picture which within the XML. I have already accessed the link to the status which is contained within a link tag.

This is the tag I'm trying to access.

```
<link type="image/png" href="http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1706928570/IMG00474-20111008-1737_normal.jpg" rel="image" >
```

The location within the XML file is line 18.

```
<feed xmlns:google="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:twitter="http://api.twitter.com/" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xml:lang="en-US" >
   <id>tag:search.twitter.com,2005:search/</id>
   <link type="text/html" href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=" rel="alternate" >
   <link type="application/atom+xml" href="http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=" rel="self" >
   <title>- Twitter Search</title>
   <link type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" href="http://twitter.com/opensearch.xml" rel="search" >

   <link type="application/atom+xml" href="http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?since_id=170944502142476289&q=&geocode=51.5069999695%2C-0.142489999533%2C10.0mi%22london%22" rel="refresh" >
   <updated>2012-02-18T18:55:19Z</updated>
   <openSearch:itemsPerPage>15</openSearch:itemsPerPage>
   <link type="application/atom+xml" href="http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?page=2&max_id=170944502142476289&q=&geocode=51.5069999695%2C-0.142489999533%2C10.0mi%22london%22" rel="next" >
   <entry>
          <id>tag:search.twitter.com,2005:170944502142476289</id>
          <published>2012-02-18T18:55:19Z</published>
          <link type="text/html" href="http://twitter.com/LondITjobs/statuses/170944502142476289" rel="alternate" >
          <title>Software Development Engineer II - London #job #jobs #hiring #career http://t.co/VsxPdWdT</title>
          <content type="html" >Software Development Engineer II - London #job #jobs #hiring #career http://t.co/VsxPdWdT</content>
          <updated>2012-02-18T18:55:19Z</updated>
          <link type="image/png" href="http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/1812202768/jr_100_normal.png" rel="image" >
          <twitter:geo>
          <google:location>London</google:location>
          <twitter:metadata>
                 <twitter:result_type>recent</twitter:result_type>
             </twitter:metadata>
          <twitter:source>twitterfeed</twitter:source>
          <twitter:lang>en</twitter:lang>
          <author>
                 <name>LondITjobs (ITjobsLondon)</name>
                 <uri>http://twitter.com/LondITjobs</uri>
             </author>
      </entry>
```

Here is my code I currently have..

```
 <?php function get_twitter($feed) {

$xml = new SimpleXmlElement(file_get_contents($feed));


foreach ($xml->entry as $item) {

    $date = date("D, dS M Y g:i:sA T", strtotime($item->published));

    echo '<a href="' . $item->link->attributes()->href . '" target="_blank">' . $item->title . '</a><br />' .'<img src='.$item->link->link->attributes()->href .'/>'.'<br />'. $item->author->name . '<br />' . '<strong>' . $date . '</strong>' . '<br />';
}

}

?>
```

At the moment I have already accessed the first link tag with the entry section of the XML and Im a little unsure on how to access the picture. I thought about doing link[0] but don't know if this is the way to go. Any suggestions?

[image: Heres what I currently have]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have finally worked out a solution.

```
'<img src="http://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image/' . $item->author->name .'" width="55" height="55"'. '>' . '</a>'
```

The user name is parsed onto the end of the URL and then this is hyperlinked back the profile of the user. All the pictures are limited to ensure consistency.